# Can't resolve dependencies with webpack 4 and bower

Tags: webpack, bower, polymer-2.x, webpack-4

I am trying to bundle my application with webpack 4, it's a application based in Polymer, with dependencies in bower, and HTML files

This is my webpack config:

```
'use strict';

const webpack = require('webpack');

/* global __dirname module require */
/* eslint comma-dangle: ["error", "never"] */
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './my-entry.html',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ['bower_components', 'node_modules'],
        descriptionFiles: ['package.json', 'bower.json']
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'babel-loader' },
                    { loader: 'polymer-webpack-loader' }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['env']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

And when I run webpack, I have the following error:

```
ERROR in ./my-page.html
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../util-custom-types/imports/currency.html' in 'C:\Workspaces\my-project'
resolve '../one-package/imports/currency.html' in 'C:\Workspaces\my-project'
  using description file: C:\Workspaces\my-project\package.json (relative path: .)
```

this import `../util-custom-types/imports/currency.html` is located inside `bower_components/util-custom-types/imports/currency.html`, and when I run `polymer serve` without bundling, it works.

Looks like webpack is missing something inside

`resolve: {
            modules: ['bower_components', 'node_modules'],`

because it doesn't looks for the file inside those folders.

this is one of the failing imports

```
<link rel="import" href="../util-custom-types/imports/currency.html">
```

I have tried some plugins on the internet, but as webpack 4 is pretty new, a lot of them are not working.

I know that if I use the import links pointing to the `bower_components` folder, like this, `<link rel="import" href=".bower_components/util-custom-types/imports/currency.html">` it will work, but it's not a valid solution, as some of the components also have the same way of importing, and I can't modify that.

So, In conclusion, I want to use html imports, pointing to a bower_components folder, like this:

`<link rel="import" href="../util-custom-types/imports/currency.html">`

to a file located in

`./bower_components/util-custom-types/imports/currency.html`

in webpack 4, without referencing to the bower_components foder.

Has anyone achieved this?

**EDIT:**

I have created a sample github project, with just a component creaated from polymer init, and a webpack configuration.

https://github.com/vlaraort/demo_polymer_webpack

It's important to be a component, no a application, 
because the html imports of polymer are not pointing to bower components, and in a application, the html imports of polymer, points to bower_components.

Component:

`<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer-element.html">`

Application:

`<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">`

To install, `npm i & bower i`

To run working polymer serve `npm run polymer:dev`
To run not-working webpack serve `npm run webpack:dev`

As you can see with the `webpack:dev`, the polymer element import is trying to fetch from `http://localhost:8080/polymer/polymer-element.html`, instead of `http://localhost:8080/bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html`, and it's failing because that.

So, the objective of the question is to understand what magic is polymer serve doing with the imports, as it resolves this link

`<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer-element.html">`

into bower_components, and how to reproduce that behaviour in webpack.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relative imports should work fine. You just need to tell webpack to resolve html files.
Add `html` to the list of extension.

```
resolve: {
    modules: ['bower_components', 'node_modules'],
    descriptionFiles: ['package.json', 'bower.json'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.html']
},
```

**EDIT:**

The sample project helped to understand what is wrong here.
The error has actually nothing to do with webpack. webpack never touches the files in `demo`. `webpack-dev-server` only loads `index.html` in the root directory, which redirects into `demo`. But nothing gets complied. This is the same as if you would run any other webserver in this directory.
You can see that by running just `webpack` without the dev server. It just compiles the `index.html`.

Let me try to explain what you want to do instead.
First, you need to load your root `index.html` file with something like [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin). This file should not get bundled, or we can't load anything.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: path.resolve(__dirname, './index.html'),
  inject: false
}),
```

In this file you need to now load everything else. Plus do some polymer magic. The [demo application of the polymer-webpack-loader explains this](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/polymer-webpack-loader/blob/master/demo/src/index.ejs).

And last, define your webpack entry points. These are now your components. Everything that gets loaded from inside of them with relative paths, including things from `bower_components`, should just work. Webpack will resolve them and bundle everything up.

The demo application from the loader is a big help, look at their implementation.
Sorry the solution isn't as simple as I first though. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but its not working correctly. For example, in my import I have `<link rel="import" href="../../polymer/polymer.html"> `, and, when I run webpack, it's trying to get the file from `http://localhost:8080/polymer/polymer.html`, but its located here `http://localhost:8080/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html`. What can be the problem?

Comment: @Del how are you importing this first file? This sounds like they are not getting compiled at all.

Comment: Hi, I am just setting the first file in the entry of the webpack config

Comment: Maybe one of the problems is that in `<link rel="import" href="../util-custom-types/imports/currency.html">` is using canonical path, so it's pointing outside my project folder, but with polymer serve is working

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error. I also don't understand why there still is `http://localhost:8080/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html`, webpack should bundle all of the html files. Can you try putting a complete example together where this happens?

Comment: It make sense! thanks for the effort!, but I can't make it work :( I have followed the demo, and I still have the same problem. If I use the link imports writing the bower_components folder, it works, but without it it doesnt. I have updated the github with my progress

Comment: @Del you are super close, just a couple small things. I opened a pull request on GitHub.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!